# Diagonalization of Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I would like to perform diagonalization of a Hermitian matrix $A$ and I know the steps but at the end I am not getting diagonal matrix with eigenvalues on the main diagonal, can anyone help me why?

Assume I choose one of the eigenvectors to be $[0 1 0]'$ and I found two other orthonormal vectors as $[1 0 0]'$ and $[0 0 1]'$. I would like to know why my final matrix $T$  such that $T'AT$ is not diagonal?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\sqrt{2}\\0&1&0\\\sqrt{2}&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why should $e_1$ and $e_3$ be eigenvectors of $A$ just because they are orthogonal to the eigenvector $e_2$?

Comment: They are not eigenvecors of A but diagonalization of hermitian matrix works as long as column of transformation matrix T are independent, and orthogonal to each other

Comment: Are you saying that for a hermitian $A$ and any unitary $T$, $T'AT$ is diagonal?

Comment: Not any T but first we calculate one of the eigenvectors then choose two other independent vector and use a gram schmit process to normalize and make them orthogonal on each other and at the end If I line up the vectors as matrix T , the T'AT is diagonal.

Comment: I see so you say that finding a *single* eigenvector is enough to diagonalize a hermitian matrix. Hm well sadly, that does not work.

Comment: Actually I figure out the answer and BTW finding one eigenvector is sufficient as well.

Comment: Very late comment, but do you mind sharing how you solved this?